# flask-bootstrap bootstrap_find_resource

Tags: flask, static, flask-bootstrap

looking to specify the themed css for `bootstrap`. can't get `bootstrap_find_resource` to look to my locally placed css files. Seems to continue to pull from the `/site-packages/flask_bootstrap` location.

the current default for `bootstrap` css is pointing here

```
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and this is the macro generating the url

```
<link href="{{bootstrap_find_resource('css/bootstrap.css', cdn='bootstrap')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

bootstrap_find_resource code pointed me to the `BOOTSTRAP_SERVE_LOCAL` config.  setting it to true gave me a local endpoint. which created the local endpoint

```
<link href="/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css?bootstrap=3.3.5.7" rel="stylesheet">
```

so I placed the bootstrap css in this local app static folder /static/bootstrap/css/.  and i verified that flask's `app.static_folder` is actually mapped to where I put the new files. still pulling from site packages and ignores my local static files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bootstrap_find_resource` is for loading static files distributed with Flask-Bootstrap. For your own files, use `url_for`.

```
{% block styles %}
    {{ super() }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='locally/placed.css') }}">
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: url_for would work and is the answer.  do you know how to go about sub classing the base.html template to provide this override?

Comment: You should use the `styles` block. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Hi @dirn I know it has been sometime, but does that mean that the style block will have to be included in the base.html if I were to extend from it? Or I can put it at the top of any of my html files referring to the css? Thanks!